# Reading HTTP Response as it comes in

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, httpclient

A client has a page which when called starts a long running process and intermittently spits out its progress as it goes

In the format

```
[dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss] - Process Started
[dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss] - CSV Imported
[dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss] - Process 10% complete
```

Then 30 seconds later it might write out :

```
[dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss] - User x Created
[dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss] - User y Created
[dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss] - Process 20% complete
```

etc... it takes 10-20 minutes to run, we dont have access to the code for this page.

What I have been asked to do is to call this page from one of the other applications, consume the output and give a realtime update on our dashboard.

My first thought was was to use an http client call .GetStreamAsync() and have a loop reading the stream intermittently and reporting back on the last thing that was written out.

This was my first attempt :

```
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {

                httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Timeout.Infinite);
                var requestUri = "http://localhost:64501/Page1.aspx";
                var stream = httpClient.GetStreamAsync(requestUri).Result;

                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        var currentLine = reader.ReadLine();
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    }
                }
            }
```

However 
var currentLine = reader.ReadLine();

Appears to block and wait for the response to complete before returning anything..

I need to be able to read the stream as it comes in.. Is this possible?

Comment: This should work, maybe there's no real new line but a `<br/>`, if this code was prepared to be used in a web page makes more sense than `\r\n`. Instead of reading lines with a streamreader use a plain stream, read chunks of binary data and then use Encoding to transform to UTF8 string each chunk you receive.

Comment: Thats what I thought but we dont appear to get a response until the final Process 100% complete message is sent and the response ends...

Comment: But have you tried to read it with the stream instead of StreamReader?

Comment: It took a few minutes for what you meant in the first comment to sink in.

Youre exactly right, there are no line endings (Not even <br/>) its just one continuous string.

The page we are calling is essentially writing one continuous string to the response and the client is being left to format it..

If you want to answer the question Ill flag that it resolved the problem! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in `ReadLine`, the server may be not sending lines (something logic as it seems to be prepared to be sent to a web page where newlines are ignored) so you need to read chuncks of data and convert those to strings:

```
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {

            httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Timeout.Infinite);
            var requestUri = "http://localhost:64501/Page1.aspx";
            var stream = httpClient.GetStreamAsync(requestUri).Result;

            string read = "";
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            while(!stream.EndOfStream)
            {
                int readed = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);
                read += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, readed);

                //Do whatever you need to do with the string.
            }
        }
```